# curved text after being extruded

Tags: extrude

I was following How to Make a Neon Sign in Blender  - Part 1 by Blender Guru and in this tutorial he could pull back the curves as shown in the picture 1   [image: tutorial]

however im unable to extrude the curves, here is the picture attached . thanks
[image: my output]

Comment: could you please describe a bit more what's the problem? Also maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: i don't know whether it is the reason or if it helps, but just staring at your pics...guru has checked just radius, you have checked radius and stretch